# Jquery - css rotate

Tags: jquery, css, rotation

I am using the below jQuery script to `transform:rotate` the text printed on a product based on select `input` `data-field`s.

However for some reason the text is not rotating. What is wrong with the script?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    
    var fieldId = "5f0124e773aa8"; 
    var defaultText = "my name"; 
    
    if(!jQuery('input[data-field-id="'+fieldId+'"]').length)
        return;
        
    var $el = jQuery('<div class="sw_poster_text2">').html(defaultText);
    $el.appendTo(jQuery('.woocommerce-product-gallery--with-images'));
    
    jQuery(document).on('change keyup','input[data-field-id="'+fieldId+'"]',function(){
        var v = jQuery(this).val() || defaultText;
        jQuery('.sw_poster_text2').html(v);
        
    }).trigger('change');
    $("select[data-field-id='5f01264e722ae']").change(function() {
        var transform = $(this).find('option:selected').data('wapf-label');
        if(transform == 'horizontal')
            transform = 'rotate(-0deg)';
        if(transform == 'rotate')
            transform = 'rotate(-40deg)';
        $(".sw_poster_text2").css("tranform", transform);
    });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input data-field-id="5f0124e773aa8" />
<select data-field-id="5f01264e722ae">
<option data-wapf-label="horizontal">horizontal</option>
<option data-wapf-label="rotate">rotate</option>
</select>
<div class="woocommerce-product-gallery--with-images"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: You are doing a return on main document. Check your console for errors.

Comment: Why Rotate has only 40deg of rotation?

Comment: Also, are you sure ID `5f01264e722ae` will always be `5f01264e722ae`?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I missed it at first as well - it's added dynamically

Comment: Try spelling `transform` as `transform` instead of `tranform` and you'll be good to go.

Comment: @freedomn-m ugh, really, there it is in JS :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my first answer here on Stack Overflow. Just looked at it more closely and there was just a single typo error.

In the last line, just change `tranform` to `transform`.
That will do it.

```
        $(".sw_poster_text2").css("transform", transform);
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO - we don't normally provide answers for simple typos like this; preferring to vote-close - without an answer it will get closed automatically after receiving enough votes.  Please do try on another question - once you get 50 rep you can add comments to point out typos.

Comment: Ok i will remember that